# Alternative to memcpy

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point, arduino, memcpy

I am using an Arduino to parse UDP packages sent from an application on my local network. The messages contain 36 bytes of information. The first four bytes represent one (single-precision) float, the next four bytes another one, etc.

The Arduino function udp.read() reads the data as chars, and I end up with an array

```
char data[36] = { ... };
```

I am now looking for a way to convert this into the corresponding nine floats. The only solution I have found is repeated use of this trick:

```
float f;
char b[] = {data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]};
memcpy(&f, &b, sizeof(f));
```

However, I am sure there must be a better way. Instead of copying chunks of memory, can I get away with using only pointers and somehow just tell C to interpret b as a float?

Thanks

Comment: Why not make a union to align the char array with an array of floats?

Comment: @Jim Could you provide a few details? I am new to C, so I am not used to this very low-level stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted an answer.

Comment: Please note that `memcpy(&f, b, sizeof f);` is the **only** solution that doen not make any assumptions about aligment / padding. For unpacking network packets and binary file formats, this is the way to go.

Comment: For all of these solutions, make sure that the sending application is using the same representation of float that the Arduino is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
union Data
{
   char  data[36];
   float f[9];
};


union Data data;
data.data[0] = 0;
data.data[1] = 0;
data.data[2] = 0;
data.data[3] = 0;

fprintf(stdout,"float is %f\n",data.float[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't heard about union before. Quite a clever little thing!

Comment: It's really old. People don't use it much anymore.  Useful for int to bits as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could just read directly into the buffer

```
float data[9];
udp.read((char*)data, sizeof(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is dangerous and technically not well defined, and the way you are doing it is better.

That said, on some platforms you can get away with:

```
float *f1 = (float *)data;
float *f2 = (float *)(data + 4);
```

---

Also, in your code I see no reason why you don't `memcpy` directly from `data + offset`.

Comment: What, exactly, do you think is undefined about the snippet you show?

Comment: @delnan A specific implementation might have some peculiarities, for example some storage set aside for floating-point stuff and some "general" storage for other stuff. When you make a `float *` point into the general storage hilarity might ensue.

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I was looking for. I tried something along the same lines, but I somehow managed to mess up my pointers. Thanks for the memcpy tip; I have never used that function before.

Comment: @cnicutar Any example of implementations doing something like that? I don't think the C standard permits such nonsense (and yes, it's nonsense from a hardware design perspective). I know that sometimes vendors take standard conformance not very serious, but that's not a carte blanche to call everything potentially undefined. A more realistic hazard might be violation of the strict aliasing rule (leading to "wrong" optimization), but that one doesn't apply to `char`.

Comment: @delnan I don't have any specific examples and you obviously know more than I do about the issue. But if the standard doesn't guarantee this type of conversion - and it doesn't - then it isn't safe. I don't see anything in the standard that prevents such a weird execution model but would love if you would prove me wrong.

Comment: @cnicutar I would agree that it's dangerous and undefined if the standard actually didn't guarantee this to work, but AFAIK it *does*, insofar that `char *`<->`float *` casting and access is not illegal. There are a number of potential issues like alignment, the size of `float`, its internal representation but this is all implementation-defined, not undefined (and at least the alignment and size parts can be worked around somewhat portably). I'm not a language lawyer but I'm pretty certain about this.

Comment: Bad things can happen on architecture that requires aligned memory access and data points to not properly aligned memory location (e.g. not to word boundaries). On IA32 unaligned memory access is simply slower. On other archs it can be more dangerous.

Comment: @delnan Not a language lawyer either. I found no proof but consider the following situation. Let's say you are on the Cell architecture that doesn't allow unaligned accesses to integers and you somehow construct a `char data[4]` that starts at an odd address. You can say `int *x = (int *)data` and when you dereference `x` you will trap. Would it be that far-fetched to have something similar happen when floats are involved ? True, not **undefined** but dangerous.

Comment: @cnicutar You're right, alignment is a potential issue. Along with others, which I mentioned before. Alignment specifically you can solve via one of the countless ways of specifying alignment, but yes one has to take care. It's not the "dangerous" bit I object to but the "undefined" one. Almost every low-level optimization is dangerous when working in C.

Comment: @delnan I am in full agreement with the last statement. And I think my answer was confusing since I had the word "undefined" when I meant "not well defined".

Comment: @delnan: `data` is a `char` array.  It is UB (because it breaks type-based alias analysis) to pun it with a `float *`.

Comment: @tmyklebu Reference? As far as I am aware, the strict aliasing rule does not prohibit any kind of aliasing `char *` with `T *`, it prohibits `T *` aliasing `U *` for most `T != U`. Every correct TBAA takes this into account.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, and that's what's going on here.  `data` is an array of `char` being accessed as an array of `float`.  This is illegal, but you can go the other way---you can access an array of `float` through a `char *`.

Comment: @tmyklebu Ah yes, it's possible that I missed that distinction. Still, could you give a reference so that I can overwrite my memory without doubt?

Comment: @delnan: Your memory is correct.  Looking at n1124, 6.5 point 6 defines "effective type" and 6.5 point 7 condemns you to undefined behaviour if you access an object with an incompatible type that isn't char.

Comment: @delnan, in cnicutar's code, the char array might not be correctly aligned for float

Comment: @MattMcNabb Read the rest of the comments. I already talked about that *twice*.